# mod_pagespeed breaks css links

Tags: php, css, mod-pagespeed

I have a PHP script that scraps a page and rewrites it in a different way with a different layout etc.

On the top of the PHP generated page I have a serie of `<link rel=stylesheet href=*.css>`.

I've updated my server yesterday and today I've noticed that mod_pagespeed is messing up with these links.

I get:

```
<link href="http://example.com/A.mycss1.css+css,,_v3,,_style.css,,qv==2+css,,_v3,,_typography.css,,qv==1+css,,_v3,,_responsive.css,Mcc.i_KwDiEdXd.css.pagespeed.cf.ybNw-Cca4d.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And obviously it breaks the entire page layout.

I've tired disabling mod_pagespeed within `.htaccess`:

```
ModPagespeed off
```

But the result is the same.
How can I fix it?

Atm I've disabled it globally but I'd like to understand how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This URL is the expected result of the [combine_css](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-css-combine) and [rewrite_css](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-css-rewrite) filters. combine_css combines multiple CSS files into one and leaves URLs like foo.css+bar.css.pagespeed.cc.hash.css. rewrite_css minifies and rewrites the images inside CSS. These should not be breaking the layout of your page.

However, as a temporary work-around you could add:

```
ModPagespeedDisableFilters combine_css
```

to your config file. Editing `.htaccess` should also work, but you have to edit `.htaccess` for the HTML file directory, not the CSS directory.

But as I said before, it's surprising that this is breaking your page. Please send us an email at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mod-pagespeed-discuss so that we can find the root of the problem.

Comment: Thank you I will do what you've said when I come back from work.

Comment: Ops.. never tried again.. maybe some day I'll give it a try ^^"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a messed up stylesheet so I tried to disable combine_css and that did not fix everything, so I added a disable on rewrite_css too.

Using cpanel, please check https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA4/Modify+Apache+Virtual+Hosts+with+Include+Files#82e9ab17b6bb4803b5834eecb7e0ef57 to see how to update your autogenerated .conf file without editing it directly.